# Duplicate symbol from definition in function

Tags: c

I am trying to define a global logger one time in a header file doing the following:

```
// log.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "log.h"

void log_add_file(const char* filename)
{
    printf("Adding file %s", filename);
}

void log_log(const char* filename, const char* function, int line, int level, ...)
{
    printf("LOG");
}
```

```
// logmain.c
#include "log.h"

int main(void)
{
    log_add_file("log.txt");
    log_info("Hello");
}
```

```
#ifndef LOG_H
#define LOG_H
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEFAULT_FORMAT "[%(levelname)] %(time) %(name) - %(filename):%(funcName):%(lineno) - %(msg)"

enum LogLevel {
    DEBUG=10,
    INFO=20,
    WARN=30,
    ERROR=40,
};

struct logger {
    int         level;
    const char* format;
    FILE**      handlers;
    int         num_handlers;
};
struct logger Logger = {INFO, DEFAULT_FORMAT, NULL, 1};

#define log_debug(...) log_log(__FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, DEBUG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define log_info(...) log_log(__FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, INFO , __VA_ARGS__)
#define log_warn(...) log_log(__FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, WARN , __VA_ARGS__)
#define log_error(...) log_log(__FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, ERROR , __VA_ARGS__)

void log_add_file(const char* filename);
void log_log(const char* filename, const char* function, int line, int level, ...);
#endif
```

The offending line is:

```
struct logger Logger = {INFO, DEFAULT_FORMAT, NULL, 1};
```

And the compiler says:

```
duplicate symbol _Logger____ in:
    /var/folders/b1/mmc6r_jj00ldzr2prvqzy56m0000gp/T/log-9f31fa.o
    /var/folders/b1/mmc6r_jj00ldzr2prvqzy56m0000gp/T/logmain-220d4d.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What is the compiler saying in this case? First, why would a duplicate symbol matter here if `logmain.c` doesn't call `log.c` and vice versa? And secondly, what would be a way to resolve this?

Do I just add in the word `static` and call it a day? Or can that lead to other unintended consequences? Basically, I want all files to have the exact same `Logger` to use that includes it (a singleton).

Comment: Don’t define variables in headers, just declare it as extern and initialize in a single code file. Now it will be created in two object files which causes this issue.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen is that better than static?

Comment: If you want to use the same struct from multiple places rather than have several of them, yes

Comment: Sounds like a job for `extern`.